# Using method of undetermined coefficients to approximate first order equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

Find the series representation for the following differential equation,

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=x+\sin y$$

$$y(0)=0$$

My work:

We assume that it has the following representation for y

$$y=c_0+c_1+c_2+c_3x^3+...=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_n(x-x_0)^n$$

$$c_1+2c_2x+3c_3x^2+4c_4x^3=x+\sin(c_0+c_1x+c_2x^2+c_3x^3+...)$$

Using Taylor's series method I am able to do it. But I want to use undetermined coefficients.

$$c_2=\frac{1}{2}$$

I think it can be done by differentiating the function again, is there another way to figure the rest?

Comment: "Using Taylor's series method I am able to do it": so what more do you want ? You are already using the method of indeterminate coefficients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculating the powers of your series for $y$ in order to plug them into the power series for $\sin y$ is very tedious. Your idea of differentiating is right: Let $s(x)=\sin y(x)$ and $c(x)=\cos y(x)$. Then, you have a system of differential equations
\begin{align}
y'(x)&=x+s(x)\\
s'(x)&=y'(x)c(x)\\
c'(x)&=-y'(x)s(x)
\end{align} 
and the initial conditions are $y(0)=0$, $s(0)=0$ and $c(0)=1.$
With $$s(x)=\sum^\infty_{k=0}a_kx^k$$ and $$c(x)=\sum^\infty_{k=0}b_kx^k,$$
you get a system of recurrences for your unknown coefficients $a_k$, $b_k$ and $c_k$, starting from $c_0=0$, $a_0=0$ and $b_0=1$. The same ideas (though written in integral form) are used in this 
[sandbox](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/59ba5565260d3c563810df49) calculating your $c_k$:
\begin{align}
c_{0}&=0.0\\
c_{1}&=0.0\\
c_{2}&=0.5\\
c_{3}&=0.166666666666667\\
c_{4}&=0.0416666666666667\\
c_{5}&=0.00833333333333333\\
c_{6}&=0.00138888888888889\\
c_{7}&=-0.00277777777777778\\
c_{8}&=-0.00295138888888889\\
c_{9}&=-0.00167824074074074\\
c_{10}&=-0.000696373456790123\\
c_{11}&=-0.000210613075196408\\
c_{12}&=1.73903385708942e-06\\
c_{13}&=6.64992158047714e-05\\
c_{14}&=6.09324285539563e-05\\
c_{15}&=3.690742449423e-05\\
c_{16}&=1.69183736439957e-05\\
c_{17}&=5.12890685725227e-06\\
c_{18}&=-2.22041621489253e-07\\
c_{19}&=-1.76339027739769e-06\\
c_{20}&=-1.60563106392873e-06\\
\end{align}